# Sharrre Google+ not counting

Tags: php, curl

We have sharrre up and running on fixmypcstore.com, but the Google+ counter does not increase.

Added the curl to the js, sharrre.php is at the proper location.

```
$('#googleplus').sharrre({
share: {
googlePlus: true
},
urlCurl: 'http://fixmypcstore.com/wp-content/themes/fmpc/js/sharrre.php',
enableHover: false,
enableTracking: true,
click: function(api, options){
api.simulateClick();
api.openPopup('googlePlus');
}
});
```

Any idea? Curl is enabled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with `sharrre.php` itself.

Several open incidents on the project's GitHub:

- https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/168 (yours)
- https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/157
- https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/150
- https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/121
- https://github.com/Julienh/Sharrre/issues/137

Suggest you look at alternatives, or implementing it natively using each provider's code snippets.